# How to add NGINX HTTP Header Authentication:Bearer and verify using NGINX-JS

Tags: nginx

How to implement NGINX HTTP Header Authentication:Bearer?

Then use NJS to verify it?
Or any idea to protect the files using NGINX with NJS?

Sample: if the user put this link ("http://example.com/files/image.jpg") on the browser, the user can't access it unless the request has Header Authentication: Bearer.

This is the current configuration for now. I forward the request to my site files.

Now, I want to protect them using HTTP header (Authentication: Bearer)

Here's inside my nginx.conf

```
    js_include authentication.js;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location /files/ {
            resolver my_private_ip_address;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            proxy_pass              http://example.com;
        }

        location /auth {
            js_content authenticate;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

For now, this is my authentication.js. Just to test if NJS works.

```
function authenticate(r) {
    r.return (200, "Hello Config \n");
}
```

Is it possible to use NJS to verify the request if it has Header Authentication:Bearer?

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/xeioex/njs-examples#secure-hash-secure_link_hash but I think it would be better to use another nginX extension http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. I want to use Nginx with http_auth_request_module.
Then, use Nginx nginx-module-njs for user authentication. But I don't have the idea how to implement that. I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Okay, then take a look at https://github.com/xeioex/njs-examples#getting-arbitrary-field-from-jwt-as-a-nginx-variable-jwt where it shows how to extract a given field from the JWT token. Once you have the value from the JWT token you can do your checks (whatever they are) and return either 200 or 403.

Comment: I'm confused how to set up like these proxy_pass `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;` and `proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;`

Comment: In order to use http_auth_request module you should place `auth_request /auth;` inside the protected location (e.g. the `/files` location). Then nginX will first internally call `/auth` and if it returns 200 then nginX will proceed with the original request otherwise it will cancel it.

Comment: Yes, I able to do that. but when I add the Authorization header, it returns `InvalidArgument` `Unsupported Authorization Type` `Authorization` `Bearer abcdefg12345`

How can I be able to solve this?

Comment: You should provide a valid Bearer - for example eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTU4NDcyMzA4NX0.eyJpc3MiOiJuZ2lueCIsInN1YiI6ImFsaWNlIiwiZm9vIjoxMjMsImJhciI6InFxIiwienl4IjpmYWxzZX0.Kftl23Rvv9dIso1RuZ8uHaJ83BkKmMtTwch09rJtwgk

Comment: Same, it doesn't work also

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and even quite simple. At first, you need to tell Nginx to make an authentication sub-request before it goes to the proxy_pass. Just add the "auth_request /auth" directive to your location block or to the server block (if you want to have this check for every request inside this configuration). The second thing is the NJS function, which needs to check whether an Authorization token exists in the request headers or not. Here is the example code:

```
function authenticate(r) {
   var headerValue = '';
   if (r.headersIn.hasOwnProperty('Authorization')) {
        var m = r.headersIn.Authorization.match(/Bearer\s+(.+)/);
    
        if (m !== null && typeof m[1] !== 'undefined') {
            headerValue = m[1];
        }
    }
    
    // if there is no header you can simply
    if (headerValue.length > 0) {
      r.return(401);
      return;
    } else {

      // if there is a header you can validate them or simply return 200
      r.return(200);
      return;
    } 
}
```